# Fence to Fence Post Gap, Fix a Leaning Fence

Tags: wood, fence, post, nails, brackets

There is a big gap (at least 3") between the new fence at one side and old fence at perpendicular side. As you can see in the pic, the old fence is not connecting to the new fence post. Whoever install the new fence (different neighbors) just left the old fence hanging.

If I want to DIY this, what is the easiest and safest way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is that post even in the ground?

Comment: Yes. Concrete base.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the same fasteners they used for the 2x4s to the post. Align a sister 2x4, 2' is enough, to your 2x4s and fasten away. If you don't have a nail gun, I'd use screws for the sistering so it make it easier to align things up. Nice thing is that you just gained 3" of additional land.

Comment: Good idea. BTW the 3" additional land is on top of a steep hill, so not really useful, but its good to know. Thanks